# How to specify MinGW64 for codeblocks 17.02 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, gcc, mingw, code-blocks

I have downloaded CodeBlocks 17.02 without mingw and installed it, then I downloaded MinGW64 from here(https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) and only changed the architecture option from `i686` to `x86_64` during the installation and left the rest as default. Then tried to add this path to system paths: `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin`. But when I opened the CodeBlocks, it couldn't find the compiler. Also when I go to `settings>compiler` and try to set `GNU GCC compiler` it says: can not find the compiler!

How should I specify the MinGW64 for CodeBlocks om Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I explain the procedure with the ZIP files which does not requires administrator privilege or a setup.exe, just extract those with any decompression tool. This procedure is focused on C/C++. These settings may vary in other languages. The required links will be in last section.

1. Download [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads) and [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) from it's download page, the file name will be like 'codeblocks-17.12-nosetup.zip' and 'x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z' respectively. The mingw-w64 file may be with [seh or sjlj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685229/8928481) Extract those in any drive or any folder with [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). For example, here I choose `E:\CodeBlocks` and `E:\mingw64`.
2. Open CodeBlocks.exe from that extraction folder. There will be a warning like 'No compiler found'. Go to Settings > Compiler > Global Compiler Settings > Toolchain executables > Compiler's Installation Directory. Make sure GCC is default compiler. Choose the extraction folder of mingw-w64 (here `E:\mingw64`). Then select the compiler, linker, make programs one-by-one. The window will look like this screenshot:

[image: CodeBlocks_Compiler_Settings]

Now it is ready to go. These configurations are saved in "%AppData%\CodeBlocks\default.conf` file.

#### Links:

- CodeBlocks:

  - [Download Page](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads)
  - [SourceForge Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/)
- mingw-w64:

  - [Download Page](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download)
  - [SourceForge Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/)