# installing MinGW-x64 in code blocks windows 10 error: No such file or directory found

Tags: mingw

I am trying to change code blocks configuration to work with min gw x64'. i tried the method [How to specify MinGW64 for codeblocks 17.02 on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1337274/how-to-specify-mingw64-for-codeblocks-17-02-on-windows-10?newreg=ac152296dfb142df94eca2263a6c6cf8). but still i am getting following error

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
\Users\rajesh_chaurasiya\Documents\p4.o||No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: First install [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/). Then install mingw-w64 (bot 64bit and 32 bit) toolchain. You can google this step. Then specify that path.

Comment: @Biswapriyo i did what you suggested. but i am still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i can compile and run my program with mingw-x64. with c++14 & c++17 enabled. i don't know the reason but i was not able to build because i think i was saving my file in my document folder and i have turned on control folder access in windows security centre.so i changed location to save in driver e. may be it can help others.